# JSON.Stringify includes indexes and length of array

Tags: arrays, json, stringify

When I'm sending my array to my controller with AJAX, i convert it to JSON for ease of use.

I build my array like this:

```
$("#selectedDropdown option").each(function () {
     selectedLanguages.push($(this).val());
});
```

And I stringify it like this:

```
data["PreferredLanguages"] = $(selectedLanguages);
```

However when it reaches my controller, it appears like this:

```
"PreferredLanguages":{"0":"ZA","1":"CM","2":"GH","3":"ES","length":4}}
```

Note: It doesn't even look like an array.

This prevents me from deserializing it. How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`$(selectedLanguages)` does not stringify your array.  The `$` is the [constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) for a jQuery object.

You can use the [global `JSON` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to stringify your array:

```
data["PreferredLanguages"] = JSON.stringify(selectedLanguages);
```

You can see the differences between an array and the jQuery object by running this snippet:

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var $arr = $(arr);

console.log('$arr:', JSON.stringify($arr));
console.log('$arr is an array:', Array.isArray($arr));

console.log('arr:', JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log('arr is an array:', Array.isArray(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```